# Compare columns of same table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to compare the columns of a table and fetch the unmatched rows.Can someone help me to write a query to fetch the rows where Email_ID not in the format of Firstname.Lastname@abc.com in the below scenario.

TABLE

```html
S.no  Firstname  Lastname   Email_ID
701    Sean           Paul        Sean.Paul@abc.com
702    Mike           Tyson        Mike.Samuel@abc.com
703   Richard   Bernard      Jim.Anderson@abc.com
704    Simon   Sharma       Rita.sharma@abc.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE CHARINDEX(FirstName + '.' + LastName + '@', Email) = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like:

```
select -- some columns
from table
where Email_ID <> (FirstName + '.' + Lastname + '@abc.com')
```

?

There is nothing in SQL to prevent comparing one column with another, and – with a little more syntax – even across rows.

Answer (score 2):

Search for rows where mail address not like Concat( firstname . lastname @)

```
select * from tablename
where Email_ID NOT LIKE (Firstname + '.' + Lastname + '@%')
```

Comment: it uses `+` sign to concat